# How to assign output of os.system to a variable

Tags: python, os.system

I want to run this command from python

```
/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp
```

when I run it in python it prints the temperature to the screen and returns 0. When I try to assign it to a variable it assigns 0 too.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp')
temp=42.8'C
0
>>> temp=os.system('/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp')
temp=42.8'C
>>> temp
0
>>>
```

How can I run this command in python and assign the actual temperature to a variable?

Comment: I don't think `os.system` lets you capture the output. You could try I/O redirecting the output to a file, and reading that file in python

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: or better still, don't use `os.system()`..

Comment: Or, put another way, the only "output" of [`os.system`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) is the exit status; anything the child writes to stdout just goes right through to your own stdout.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Or just read the docs to [`os.system`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) instead of just using it blindly, which make the answer obvious…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`os.system`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) doesn't returns the output, use [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) for that.

Comment: If you look at the `os.system` docs, they explicitly tell you that it has "limitations" and that "the `subprocess` module has more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results", and that "using that module is preferable to using this function."